# Questions about government bonds that have already matured

Tags: united-states, bonds, government-bonds, maturity

I have a family member that holds some bonds issued on real paper (like from trees). I have a few questions about mature bonds:

- Does a person have an indefinite period of time to cash them in?
- Where/how does a person cash them in?
- Does the value change after the day they mature?
- Are the mature bonds able to be deposited to a retirement account any which way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you are talking about US Savings Bonds:

Here is a page that talks about [maturity dates of US Savings bonds](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/securities/res_securities_stoppedearninginterest.htm). If They aren'tSavings bonds but are another type of[US Government Bond](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/products/products.htm)

Assuming they are Savings bonds, here is information regarding [redeeming of bonds](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/ebonds/res_e_bonds_eeredeem.htm).

> **How do I redeem my EE/E Bonds?**
>
> **Electronic bonds:**     Log in to Treasury Direct and follow the directions there. The cash amount can be credited to your checking or savings account within one business day of the redemption date.
>
> **Paper bonds**    You can cash paper EE/E Bonds at many local financial institutions. We don't keep a list of banks that redeem bonds, so check with banks in your area.
>
> **What will I need to redeem a paper bond?**
>
> Before taking in the bonds to redeem them, it's usually a good idea to check with the financial institution to find out what identification and other documents you'll need.
>   When you present your paper bonds, you'll be asked to show your identity. You can do this by
>
> - being a customer with an active account open for at least 6 months at the financial institution that will be paying the bonds, or
> - presenting acceptable identification such as a valid driver's license if the >redemption value of the bonds is less than $1,000.
>
> If you are not listed as the owner or co-owner on the bond, you'll have to show that you >are entitled to cash in the bond.

The [treasury direct website](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/ebonds/res_e_bonds.htm) also discusses converting bonds, rules regarding using them for education, how often they are [credited with interest](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/ebonds/res_e_bonds_eeratesandterms_increaseinvalue.htm)